# Custom Screen resolution

Tags: resolution

I use a samsung netbook with intel atom N2100, the recommended resolution is for the netbook is1024x600 but i want to increase the screen resolution to 1024x768. I tried to use the intel graphics media accelerator 3600 control center to create a custom resolution but i keep getting the invalid resolution message. Can i use a custom resolution which is higher than my netbook's recommended resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely no, **you cannot use a custom resolution which is higher than the recommended resolution.**

For flat panel displays, there is a hard limit on how many pixels are available. Unlike on CRT displays, flat panel displays also use distinct pixels, so scaling (by anything other than an integer factor) produces a very ugly image. Hence, it is recommended to run a flat panel display at its native resolution (or an integer fraction thereof, but very few if any standard resolutions are related by integer factors to other standard resolutions, particularly in a range you are likely to find useful).

Since **the native, or recommended, resolution is also the maximum resolution** (you can't put more pixels in there), this puts a hard upper limit on the resolution you can configure in software. Attempting to configure a higher resolution will lead to some sort of error, such as the one you are experiencing.

CRTs had other issues which capped the resolution that was possible to use with a specific tube, but due to their physical design dealt more gracefully with lower resolutions, so for those, "recommended" resolution could be (and as I recall, often was) lower than the maximum possible resolution.